# Empty mutable property with non optional value

Tags: swift, swift2, reactive-cocoa

Can I create empty mutable property (or other type of property) with non optional value?

For example this is works:

```
let distributions = MutableProperty<Distributions?>(nil)
```

but I need something like this:

```
let distributions = MutableProperty<Distributions>()
```

Distribution object:

```
struct Distributions : CollectionType{

    typealias Index = Int

    private let distributions : [Distribution]

    init(distributions : [Distribution]){
        self.distributions = distributions
    }

    var startIndex: Int {
        return 0
    }

    var endIndex: Int {
        return distributions.count
    }

    subscript(i: Int) -> Distribution {
        return distributions[i]
    }

}

struct Distribution{
    let id : Int
    let dateStart : String
    let dateEnd : String
}
```

Thnx for help.

Comment: What is `Distributions`?

Comment: It's my value object

Comment: Show the code for it?

Comment: Question updated...

Comment: Maybe just use MutableProperty<Distributions!>(nil)

Comment: Distribution vs Distribution! vs Distribution? not same data type.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two ways you can do this. One, use `ignoreNil` on your signal producer.

```swift
let distributions = MutableProperty<Distributions?>(nil)

distributions.producer
    .ignoreNil()
    .startWithNext { distributions in
        // distributions is of type [Distribution]
    }
```

Two, set the initial value of the `MutableProperty` to an empty `Distributions` object.

```swift
let distributions = MutableProperty<Distributions>(Distributions(distributions: []))

// You can skip the initial value if need be
distributions.producer.skip(1)
```

Comment: For those viewing as of May 2017, `ignoreNil()` is now `skipNil()`.